# Kendo Scheduler Year View

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, customization, kendo-scheduler

I need to build a new view for kendo scheduler, which will show tasks for the whole year. After some investigation I found out that there is no year view and typical way is to extend other kind of view (month, agenda, timeline). However I am not sure if that is even possible to show tasks in the following kind of table:

(2013)<- YEAR 2014 ->(2015)

\  JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC

1

2

3

4

...

31

So rows are days of month, columns are month. And a simple navigation for years. Can anybody give me an insight of how can this be done?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it is to do your own scheduler from scratch. The kendo scheduler is not as flexible as you want.

Comment: Rather than Scheduler, its better to use Grid View through which you will have more control over sending requests as well as view template for cells.